# is it possible to ask about list of opensource or commercial libraries in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions, list-questions

I want to find possible opensource or commercial libraries list (or better comparison of them or not just list of them) for particular task in one languages (for example converting image type in C#).

Is this question is also banned in Stack Overflow because of software recommendation?

Comment: Assuming you meant *banned* instead of *banded*, then yes, such questions would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes banned  or yes possible?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: It's off topic. Don't ask it.

Comment: then what is it down vote now for this question ?  I know "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource".
I did not wanted to asked favorite tools asked possibilities

Comment: How are those two things different? Do you think people are going to list their *least* favorite tool when you ask for possibilities?

Comment: good question, yes there might be 4 possibilities and one guy says there is not any opensource and the whole list is these 4 commercials

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that type of question is still banned, as it is essentially asking for a list of recommendations. The purpose for banning these types of questions is that they inevitably attract spam answers. If you can imagine that the majority of answers to your question will end up being a link to a commercial product, then the question will probably be closed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75521/are-recommendation-questions-an-acceptable-kind-of-list-type-question-or-should